# API Python smartsheet can't connect with SDK

Tags: python, smartsheet-api

I'm pretty new to Python and I'm trying to connect to smartsheet with API.
I have ran "pip install smartsheet-python-sdk" and it installed smartsheet as I can find it under "lib"

This is code I have found and supposed to work(I replaced the token with the token)

```
# Import.
import smartsheet

# Instantiate smartsheet and specify access token value.
smartsheet = smartsheet.Smartsheet('Token_here')

# Get all columns.
action = smartsheet.Sheets.get_columns('Template for Bram', include_all=True)
columns = action.data

# For each column, print Id and Title.
for col in columns:
    print(col.id)
    print(col.title)
    print('')
```

It shows this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bram\Desktop\smartsheet.py", line 2, in <module>
    import smartsheet
  File "C:\Users\bram\Desktop\smartsheet.py", line 5, in <module>
    smartsheet = smartsheet.Smartsheet('token_here')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Smartsheet'
```

Now I'm not sure what my next step is. I think I have followed all of the appropriate steps. When I run `import smartsheet` by itself it won't error out.
What am I doing wrong?

Thank you

Update***

After using the code from the github page and implementing my token and sheet id I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bvanhout\Desktop\test23.py", line 58, in <module>
    sheet = ss.Sheets.get_sheet(sheet_id)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\smartsheet\sheets.py", line 460, in get_sheet
    response = self._base.request(prepped_request, expected, _op)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\smartsheet\smartsheet.py", line 178, in request
    res = self.request_with_retry(prepped_request, operation)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\smartsheet\smartsheet.py", line 242, in request_with_retry
    return self._request(prepped_request, operation)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\smartsheet\smartsheet.py", line 210, in _request
    raise UnexpectedRequestError(rex.request, rex.response)
UnexpectedRequestError: (<PreparedRequest [GET]>, None)


# TODO: Update this with the ID of your sheet to update
sheet_id = 48568543424234
```

I printed ss and ss.Sheets and both do not reflect the actual token or sheet_id

```
>>> print (ss.Sheets)
<smartsheet.sheets.Sheets object at 0x0000000003874438>
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the problem is that you are using a local variable with the same name as the module ('smartsheet')

Please take a look at the sample here: https://github.com/smartsheet-samples/python-read-write-sheet

Comment: Thank you, yes I had a "smartsheet.py" program on my desktop as well. I have deleted this file and will try again!

Comment: New errors are coming up, I have edited this in my question in *Update

Comment: Without seeing your source code, it's difficult for anyone to help. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask